Qiskit simulation failed and returned the following error message
I am trying to compute some unitary matrix for some big circuit on GPU using qiskit-aer, specifically a 11 qubits circuit with the following error:
Simulation failed and returned the following error message:
ERROR:  [Experiment 0] ChunkContainer::StoreUintParams size = 4107/266 iChunk = 0 : cudaErrorInvalidValue

I do not understand what the issue is or how to fix it, the same kind of circuit works with 10 qubits and I should not be short on memory as I am running the experiment on a 32gb V100
Here the code to reproduce the issue
import time
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.quantum_info import random_unitary

seed = 42

def create_random_unitary(num_qubits, seed=None):
    return random_unitary(2 ** num_qubits, seed=seed)

num_qubits = 11

circuit = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)

gate1_qubits = list(range(0, num_qubits))

# Gate 2 spans the second set of qubits
gate2_qubits = list(range(0, num_qubits))

left_unitary = create_random_unitary(len(gate1_qubits), seed)
right_unitary = create_random_unitary(len(gate2_qubits), seed)

circuit.unitary(left_unitary, gate1_qubits)
circuit.unitary(right_unitary, gate2_qubits)

# save a fig of the circuit in pics folder
circuit.draw(output='mpl', filename=f'pics/{num_qubits}.png')

simulator = AerSimulator(method='unitary', device='GPU')

circuit.save_unitary()
# transpiled_circuit = transpile(circuit, simulator) ## doesn't matter

start_time = time.time()

job = simulator.run(circuit)
result = job.result()
unitary_matrix = result.get_unitary(circuit)

end_time = time.time()

execution_time_ms = (end_time - start_time) * 1000

print(execution_time_ms)


Can you add some code to reproduce the issue?

@luciano added the code to reproduce the issue

I'm assuming you're trying to benchmark your GPUs performance but if you're not then removing device='GPU' printed 20046.831846237183 on my local machine and on the qbraid server which should resolve your issue.
Remember that your circuit matrix blows up exponentially so a 2^10 size matrix might have been fine but 2^11 for 11 qubits is double the size this might be too big for your GPU which is suggested by the error message.

Yes, I am trying to benchmark my gpu performances.
Also there is no reason to believe that 11 qubits are too many for the architecture, as I was able to run the same simulation on 10 qubits on a 8Gb GPU, therefore 32Gb should be enough for just one qubit more; moreover the error message for being out of memory is slightly different

What GPU do you have? Currently only NVIDIA GPUs have support according to this https://qiskit.github.io/qiskit-aer/tutorials/1_aersimulator.html

As stated in the question, I am using an NVIDIA Tesla V100
